# Python update package version in requirements.txt

Tags: python, pip

I have a requirement.txt file with the list of python package to install. One of the packages is `psycopg2==2.6.2` I need to update this package to `psycopg2==2.7`. I tried to install by `pip3 install psycopg2` But it doesn't affect requirement.txt file. Can you please point me in the right direction?

Comment: Sure, if you want to find out on your own, check out `pip freeze` and you need to know a bit about redirecting stdout to a file.

Answer (score 14):

Notice that running `pip3 install psycopg2` doesn't respect the `requirements.txt` file. To upgrade this package you need to use [`-U`](https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/reference/pip_install/#cmdoption-u) option:

```
pip3 install -U psycopg2
```

which is a shorthand for:

```
pip3 install --upgrade psycopg2
```

After that, you can update your `requirements.txt` with the following command:

```
pip freeze > requirements.txt
```

If you're looking for a solution to automatically update the `requirements.txt` file after you upgrade package/packages, you can use [`pip-upgrader`](https://github.com/simion/pip-upgrader).

**Installation:**

```
pip install pip-upgrader
```

**Usage:**

```
pip-upgrade
```

The above command auto-discovers the requirements file and prompts for selecting upgrades. You can also specify a path to the requirements file or/and specify a package to upgrade:

```
pip-upgrade /path/to/requirements.txt -p psycopg2
```

Answer (score 7):

As you've discovered, pip doesn't update the requirements file. So the workflow you'd likely want to use is:

- Update the version of psycopg2 in your requirements file from 2.6.2 to 2.7
- Run pip install with the upgrade flag

`pip3 install -U -r requirements.txt`

If you're familiar with tools like `npm` that **do** update the version in the catalog file, you may be interested in using [pipenv](https://github.com/pypa/pipenv), which manages your dependencies and the virtual environment for you, much like `npm` does.

If you don't know the latest version of your package, then use pip to figure it out:

```
$ pip list --outdated | grep psycopg2                                                                           
psycopg2 (2.7.3.2) - Latest: 2.7.4 [wheel]
```

Comment: That flow is only valid if you know the newest version of the package beforehand (newest, since I assume this is what the OP meant by upgrading).

Answer (score 1):

Piping the output of pip freeze into `requirements.txt` leads to a file that includes your codes dependencies and the dependencies of the dependencies, leading to a bloated `requirements.txt` file.

If you:

- like to maintain a lean `requirements.txt` file with only your dependencies
- you wish to update all packages in `requirements.txt` to their latest versions
- you want to update the packages installed in your `venv` with the updated versions

then you can do the following:

```
pip install --user pur
pur # updates versions listed in requiremnts.txt to the latest version
pip install --upgrade -r requirements.txt
```

At this point you may need to selectively downgrade packages to avoid package dependency conflicts.

See https://pypi.org/project/pur/ for more info.

Answer (score 0):

you can try:

```
pip install --upgrade --force-reinstall -r requirements.txt
```

You can also ignore installed package and install the new one :

```
pip install --ignore-installed -r requirements.txt
```